The "&" character breaks passwords that are stored in the web config
I have an ASP.NET MVC3 C# .NET Application running on IIS 7.5.
We have a Windows NT service account we Impersonate in our code in order to read/write documents to a file share. The user id is compiled in the code and the service account password is stored in the web.config file.
The password contains an ampersand character (i.e.: p&ssword).
This broke the site. When accessing the site we received this error :"Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request".
Here is the code that uses the password:
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(Common.SVC_PWD);

bool isSuccess = LogonUser(
    @"my_svc_acct",
    "my.domain.net",
    password,
    LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token
);

Why would this cause the site to break?
i tried turning computer off an on again but nothing changed

What happens when you try to run that code locally?

Please show us the web.config file.

Like I said in the Staging Ground: You are going to need to show us how you are storing the password. Show the XML or JSON config file. Please also show the function definition for the LogonUser import.

Out of curiosity, why are you not just running the whole app under that user, rather than impersonating? Also ideally you should use a gMSA instead of a standard user account, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/78925299/14868997 for how to do impersonation for a gMSA
